# PHP PDO only last value of array gets inserted using bindValue & bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When below code is executed, only the last value of the array `charlie` gets inserted in the table.

```
$this->array = $array; //Array ( [0] => alpha [1] => bravo [2] => charlie )

$query = "INSERT INTO test SET Name = :Name";
$sql = $this->conn->prepare($query);

foreach($this->array as $k => &$v) {
    $sql->bindValue(":Name" , $v , PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$sql->execute();
```

Im getting the same result using `bindParam` as well.

Can someone help me point out what I'm missing.

I'm totally baffled.

Comment: Call execute inside the loop.

Comment: You need to put that execute inside of your loop, not outside, or it will only insert the last bound value.

Comment: You also could use `$this->array` and bind `Name = ?,` for each value in the array (via lazy bind `execute($this->array)`). Then you only need 1 query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only executing the insert with the last value as it's the last value that is bound to the statement. Call execute in each iteration of the loop.

```
foreach($this->array as $k => &$v) {
    $sql->bindValue(":Name" , $v , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how `bindParam` is intended to be used:

```
$this->array = $array; //Array ( [0] => alpha [1] => bravo [2] => charlie )

$query = "INSERT INTO test SET Name = :Name";
$sql = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$sql->bindParam(":Name" , $value , PDO::PARAM_STR);    
foreach($this->array as $value) {
     $sql->execute();
}
```

That is, you bind the named parameter to one of your variables so every time you execute the query the named parameter will obtain its value from the current variable value.

By contrast, if you use `bindValue` you need to re-bind each time you need to change the named parameter value:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test SET Name = :Name";
$sql = $this->conn->prepare($query);
foreach($this->array as $v) {
     $sql->bindValue(":Name" , $v , PDO::PARAM_STR);    
     $sql->execute();
}
```

The advantage of `bindParam` is that there's less allocations and passing around going on.

Comment: hi, although @nigel ren, the first one to answer my question, I greaty appreciate your explanation and insight on the proper use of `bindParam`

Comment: Why  $value = $v;?

Comment: @YourCommonSense `$value` is bound by reference using `$sql->bindParam(":Name" , $value , PDO::PARAM_STR);`  so doing `$value = $v` will make the subsequent `$sql->execute()` use the current value of `$value`

Comment: you should bind $v

Comment: @YourCommonSense that would make it a bit less obvious on what's going on here. This is code to push to production it's just to indicate how things work.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm not writing this code for me. It's for anyone who might stumble upon it in

Comment: Exactly. And for this very reason it should be *sensible* and correct example.